# PHP: Has there been variations in the return of is_string() over time?

Tags: php

I'm trying to contribute to a legacy PHP application that is very backward-compatible and I would like to be sure about the behavior of `is_string()`.

For example, I would like to assume that these facts are true in all versions of PHP. I'm honestly interested only after PHP 5.4 but it's not bad to understand if there are older versions with different behavior.

These are the cases that must be true for me since PHP 5.4 to PHP 8.2:

- `is_string(null)` → `false`
- `is_string([ "a" ])` → `false`
- `is_string("0")`  → `true`
- `is_string("")`   → `true`

Related documents:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php - official documentation that it seems to do not mention any breaking change
- https://onlinephp.io/ - tool that could be useful to you to test stuff
- https://we.phorge.it/T15190 - a related downstream discussion
- https://github.com/php/php-src - source code of PHP in which there are a lot of Unit test and maybe you are good at finding the one related to `is_string()` but it seems they are saved in files like `001.phpt` and it's not so evident to find the test from file names like these, to me

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no problem.

The cases you mentioned of the function `is_string()` are very stable and you can rely on these in all known PHP versions at least since PHP 4.0.6.

### What I have done to be sure of that

I created this small test case that does not use any new feature of PHP (do not use `throw new Exception`, do not use `[]`, etc.):

```
<?php
// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

function assert_equals($msg, $v, $expected) {
    if( $v !== $expected ) {
        echo "Fail test: $msg\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}

assert_equals('null',        is_string(null),       false);
assert_equals('array',       is_string(array("a")), false);
assert_equals('zero string', is_string("0"),        true);
assert_equals('empty',       is_string(""),         true);
```

And I tested it against these versions:

- PHP 4.0.6
- PHP 4.1.0
- PHP 4.2.0
- PHP 4.3.0
- PHP 4.4.0
- PHP 5.0.3
- PHP 5.1.0
- PHP 5.2.0
- PHP 5.3.0
- PHP 5.4.0
- PHP 5.5.0
- PHP 5.6.0
- PHP 7.0
- PHP 7.0.33
- PHP 7.1.0
- PHP 7.1.33
- PHP 7.2.0
- PHP 7.2.34
- PHP 7.3.0
- PHP 7.3.33
- PHP 7.4.0
- PHP 7.4.33
- PHP 8.0
- PHP 8.1
- PHP 8.2

And I have not noticed any change.

So, again, your test cases for `is_string()` can be assumed as really OK for any version of PHP.